# Grep list files once

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

I'm looking for some pattern in my project, and it's been repeated too much in some files.. How can I tell grep to show only once each file?

I'm using:

```
grep -R "my_pattern" *
```

Comment: If you just want the names of the files, then @EtanReisner 's suggestion is the way to go. Can you clarify if it is the case?

Comment: well.. Etan comment is perfectly valid to me, but even better if you can see a piece of code as I've seen in the answers :) Nicolas is my chosen as it keeps the syntax colour!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this, it will make grep only print the first match:

```
grep -m 1 -R "pattern" *
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "uniq" command:  http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq

```
grep -R "my_pattern" * | sort -u
```

This will sort and give you unique values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "count" functionality:

`grep $TERM -crl $DIR`

The `-c` returns a count of hits in each file, and the `-l` removes any that have a count of 0

Answer (score 1):

If you want ***only the names*** of the files containing `"my_pattern"`:

```
grep -lR "my_pattern" *
```

But the above command ignores all sub-folders starting with a dot.

If you want the file names from the sub-folder `.git` containing
`"https://github.com"`:

```
grep -lR "https://github.com" .git/*
```